# Type Error: cannot call mehod get of undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to load some json data from a server with a background loading screen.
here is controller file

```
    angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

    .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
    })
    //loading backgroundscreen of loading
    .controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope, Friends, $ionicLoading) {
        $ionicLoading.show({
              template: 'Loading...'
            });
      //this will generate the error
        Friends.all().then(function(data){

            $scope.friends=data;
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });
    })
```

Here is my services file

```
 angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Friends', function($http) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var friends ;


  return {
    all: function() {
        $http.get('http://www.root5solutions.com/ionictest/get.json').then(function(msg){
              console.log("console output"+msg.data);
              friends=msg.data;
              console.log("from server"+msg.data);
          });   
      return friends;
    },
    get: function(friendId) {
      // Simple index lookup
      return friends[friendId];
    }
  }
});
```

I am getting console error

```
Type Error:cannot call method get of undefined.
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your service is not returning promise, but you are waiting for deferred object in your controller.

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Friends', function($http) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var friends ;


  return {
    all: function() {
        return $http.get('http://www.root5solutions.com/ionictest/get.json');
    },
    get: function(friendId) {
      // Simple index lookup
      return friends[friendId];
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you give answer for this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909257/ionic-refresher-working-not-properly)

Comment: Sorry im didnt used ionic fw )